# Полуботки чи полуботинки?

Tags: вибір-слова, росіянізм

Недавно у статті натрапила на одне цікаве слово — *полуботки.* Воно асоціюється в мене з Павлом Полуботком — відомим українським гетьманом. І [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) дає визначення *полуботків*, як український козацько-старшинський рід. Але у статті це слово означало один з видів взуття. У [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/polubotky) знайша визначення — чоботи з короткими халявами. І натрапила на ще одне схоже слово — [*полуботинки*](http://sum.in.ua/s/polubotynky). Але яке з цих слів є тотожне російському "полусапожки"? Чи можливе є ще якийсь, більш поширений синонім до цих слів? І чи не є слово *полуботинки* русизмом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оскільки мода посприяла тому, що ми маємо всі можливі варіанти зовнішнього виду взуття, то словникові статті накшталт наведених із СУМ можуть дати лише усталене лексичне значення слів чоботи, ботинки, полуботинки, полуботки, черевики та інше. Точно упевнитися в їхньому зовнішньому  вигляді важко.

Наприклад,

> "**полусапожки**" рос. за словником [Ожегова](http://ozhegov.info/slovar/?ex=Y&q=%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%A3%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%96%D0%9A%D0%98) є "сапогами с короткими
>   голенищами"

отже

> "**полуботки**" - "чоботи з короткими халявами"

це точне попадання в ціль.

Далі. Маємо

> "**Черевики**" в [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/cherevyky) як "Вид невисокого взуття переважно на шнурках
>   або ґудзиках".

Тому маємо право казати "черевики" замість "полуботки".
Але маємо в тому ж [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/botynky) статтю про "**Ботинки**" із приміткою "розмовне, рідко" і вказівкою "те саме, що черевики".

Застарілим визнано слово "[**боти**](http://sum.in.ua/s/boty)" в значенні знову ж таки "чобіт із короткими халявами".

І ще цікавинки:

> "[**півчобітки**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pivchobitky)" - жіночі чоботи з короткими халявами, полуботки.
>
> "**Полуботинки**" укр. в [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/polubotynky) дається як "Закриті туфлі на шнурках або
>   пряжках".

Заразом скажу, що "получобіт" в СУМ нема, хоча цілком логічно було їх там шукати.

Якщо не зважати на зауваження про шнурки і ґудзики, то маємо більш-менш чітке уявлення про взуття, середнє між туфлями і чоботами, в якого короткі халяви, на позначення якого є слова: полуботки, боти, полуботинки, черевики, півчобітки. Вживайте на свій смак.

Щодо русизма... Тут слушно нагадати, що **полу-** є цілком українською морфемою, про що можна прочитати, в багатьох джерелах, в тому числі в статті проф. О.Г. Муромцевої:

> Колишня форма родового відмінка давньоруського **полъ** в українській мові
>   остаточно формалізувалась і перетворилась у префікс...

[О. Г. МУРОМЦЕВА
СКЛАДНІ СЛОВА ЧИ ПРЕФІКСАЛЬНІ УТВОРЕННЯ?
(ПРО УТВОРЕННЯ З ПІВ-, НАПІВ-, ПОЛУ- В СУЧАСНІЙ УКРАЇНСЬКІЙ МОВІ)](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine16-10.pdf)

Тому полуботок і полуботинок хай не видаються дивними. Нормальні українські слова. Не калька.